# My List of elements doesn't clear properly?

Tags: c#, list

I am writing a program to simulate flocking behaviour on boids. I currently have a List of behaviours which a boid uses to calculate it's next movement vector. On each update the behaviours are reset and new behaviours can be added. With a population size of 100 it all works fine, though when I increase this number my List somehow isn't cleared properly. Where I should have a list size of 4, sometimes this increases to 6 with null elements and elements which are added twice instead of once. I think this might have something to do with my program loop running too fast for the calculations but I am not sure. Is there any way I can figure this out?

My Code is as follows:

```
foreach(Vehicle boid in mainFlock)
        {
            boid.behaviours.Clear();
            boid.behaviours.Add(new CohesionBehaviour(boid, mainFlock));
            boid.behaviours.Add(new SeparationBehaviour(boid, mainFlock));
            boid.behaviours.Add(new AlignmentBehaviour(boid, mainFlock));
            boid.behaviours.Add(new SeekBehaviour(boid, mainFlockTarget.Pos));

            if (boid.behaviours.Count > 4)
                Console.WriteLine(boid.behaviours);

            boid.Update(timeElapsed);
        }
```

The Console.WriteLine() should never be called, though sometimes (when I increase the population size) it prints this(simplified):

```
[cohesion,
 cohesion,
 separation,
 alignment,
 seek,
 seek]
```

and some other times(simplified):

```
[cohesion,
 separation,
 cohesion,
 null,
 alignment,
 seek]
```

it alway's seems to be a total of 6 elements.

Comment: Sounds like you're accessing the list from multiple threads at the same time. Don't do this: List is not thread-safe

Comment: yeah, this was also a thought I had but I havn't ever used diffrent threads is there a simple way I can check which threads are accessing this variable?

Comment: Sounds like you're using a timer, though? Depending on the type of timer, timer callbacks can be invoked on ThreadPool threads. Put a breakpoint on the lines which modify the list, and see what thread in the Threads window is doing that

Comment: [Here's a simple way I wrote to check if code is being called concurrently](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1YOeN1). You can do a similar thing in your code.